# Calculation of eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{apb}{\delta} - c & \frac{dpb}{\delta} \\ \frac{a(1 - p)b}{\delta} & \frac{d(1 - p)b}{\delta} - t \end{pmatrix}$$

I tried to use the characteristic polynomial but I can't factor it to find the polynomial root. Can you please help me?

Comment: The characteristic polynomials gives you a quadratic equation for the roots. Use the usual formula.

Comment: What holds you back from factoring the quadratic polynomial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{apb}{\delta} - c & \frac{dpb}{\delta} \\ \frac{a(1 - p)b}{\delta} & \frac{d(1 - p)b}{\delta} - t \end{pmatrix}$, then finding the eigenvalue of $A$ is solving the quadratic equation that one obtains from

\begin{align*}
\det{(A - x I_2)} = 0
\end{align*}

in order to $x.$ Then, $x$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$.

Computing the determinant of the LHS of the equation, you get

\begin{align*}
(c+x)(t+x) + \frac{b(cd(p-1) + d(p-1)x - ap(t+x))}{\delta} = 0.
\end{align*}

By solving this quadratic equation (like you usually do) you get

\begin{align*}
x = \frac{b(d+ap-dp) - \delta\Big(c + \sqrt{\frac{b^2(d+ap-dp)^2}{\delta^2} - \frac{2b(d(p-1)+ap)(c-t)}{\delta} + (c-t)^2 } + t\Big)}{2\delta}
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
x = \frac{b(d+ap-dp) + \delta\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b^2(d+ap-dp)^2}{\delta^2} - \frac{2b(d(p-1)+ap)(c-t)}{\delta} + (c-t)^2 }\Big) + -\delta(c+t)}{2\delta}
\end{align*}